# How to combine two jQuery animate actions?

Tags: jquery, animation

when I mouseover the div, it will show the image title, then the date will move 10px. In my code, it just show the title, but not move the date part. How to make two jquery animate action all run well? Thax.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title> </title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   $('.image').each(function() {
        $(this).hover(
             function() {
                 $('.title', this).animate({ opacity: 1 })
             },
             function() {
                 $('.title', this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0 });
             },
         function() {
                 $('.date', this).animate({ top: '+=10' })
             },
             function() {
                 $('.date', this).stop().animate({ top: '-=10' });
             })
         });
   });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="image"><img src="img1.jpg"><p class="title">test1</p><p class="date">2010</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
   $('.image').each(function() {
        $(this).hover(
             function() {
                 $('.title', this).stop(1,1).animate({ opacity: 1 });
                 $('.date', this).stop(1,1).animate({ top: '+=10' });
             },
             function() {
                 $('.title', this).stop(1,1).animate({ opacity: 0 });
                 $('.date', this).stop(1,1).animate({ top: '-=10' });
             }
        );
   });
});
```